# How to get larger range in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this command:

```
echo -n {a..z} "" | sed -f <(seq 2 1800 | factor | awk '$0*=!$3' | xargs -I@ echo 's/ /=@\n/')
```

That prints the following:

```
a=2
b=3
c=5
d=7
e=11
f=13
g=17
h=19
...
```

I'd like a have a larger range (e.g. `aa` to `zz`), but this command:

```
echo -n {aa..zz} "" | sed -f <(seq 2 1800 | factor | awk '$0*=!$3' | xargs -I@ echo 's/ /=@\n/')
```

doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: try `{a..z}{a..z}`

Comment: Do you want aa, ab, …, az, bz, … or aa, bb, cc, …?

Comment: @l0b0 1st. Mister Ipor Sircer gived me solve command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@IporSircer said](https://superuser.com/questions/1372499/how-to-get-larger-range-in-bash/1372505#comment2066584_1372499), `{a..z}{a..z}` expands to the range `aa ab ... zz`.